# CakePHP cache helper with controller action call

Tags: cakephp, caching

I've enabled cache helper properly. It works fine for static and dynamic pages both. But my homepage which has widgets for which the data are set from the controller is causing problem. Let me explain a bit.

The whole site is location based. So all queries have location as primary search condition. The index method that has pagination works just fine for any location switching. But my homepage that has a map widget uses location based data and is not working properly. When the cache is empty, it creates cache for location A, but then when I switch to location B, it still shows me the data for location A. I checked that it is skipping the controller that sets the data.

My question is how do I enable the controller action to be called every time or else my data will be wrong, isn't it? Any idea?

Comment: best thing for such a page is not to use cache at all, you can also set callbacks as true in variable $cacheAction for that particular action, For get parameters cache works great but for post parameter cache doesn't work as parameters sent through post on first time are processed only.

Comment: Not using cache is not an option. I've used callbacks => true in $cacheAction but still it doesn't solve my problem. To test, I've printed date('Y-m-d H:i:s') in controller action but I see it only first time before cache created but when the cache is created, I don't see the date output anymore. Any idea?

Comment: Cache helper caches only the view of a controller's action. It doesn't cache any variable of controller as they are not part of view files. Only get parameters will be cached seperately, Not using cache is only option left for pages with post method form.